# BlackBerry UTF-8 InputStreamReader on Socket issue

Tags: java, http, blackberry, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to read the response from a server using a socket and the information is UTF-8 encoded.  I'm wrapping the InputStream from the socket in an InputStreamReader with the encoding set to "UTF-8".

For some reason it seems like only part of the response is read and then the reading just hangs for about a minute or two and then it finishes.  If I set the encoding on the InputStreamReader to "ISO-8859-1" then I can read all of the data right away, but obviously not all of the characters are displayed correctly.

Code looks something like the following

```
socketConn = (SocketConnection)Connector.open(url);
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(socketConn.openInputStream(), "UTF-8");
```

Then I read through the headers and the content.  The content is chunked and I read the line with the size of each chunk (convert to decimal from hex) to know how much to read.

I'm not understanding the difference in reading with the two encodings and the effect it can have because it works without issue with ISO-8859-1 and it works eventually with UTF-8, there is just the long delay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was already removing the chunk sizes on the fly so I ended up doing something somewhat similar to the IOUtilities answer.  Instead of using an InputStreamReader I just used the InputStream.  InputStream has a read method that can fill an array of bytes, so for each chunk the code looks something like this

```
byte[] buf = new buf[size];
is.read(buf);
return new String(buf, "UTF-8");
```

This seems to work, doesn't cause any delays and I can remove the extra information about the chunks on the fly.

Comment: Generally speaking, decoding a partial UTF-8 stream like this could cause errors. Since each UTF-8 character may consist of several bytes, when decoding arbitrarily sized chunks of it you could end up with the first part of a character at the end of one chunk, and the rest of that character in the beginning of next chunk, giving the wrong decoding result on both chunks. In your particular case you know the size of each chunk and they are guaranteed to decode properly so this ought to work fine. Uhm, yeah... I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: That does make sense!  Thanks, this is a corner case I may need to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get the reason of the delay.

You may try another way of getting the data from the network:

```
byte[] data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(socketConn.openInputStream());
```

I believe the above should be passed without delay. Then having got the bytes from network you can start data processing. Note you can always get a `String` from bytes representing a string in UTF-8 encoding:

```
String stringInUTF8 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

**UPDATE**: see the second comment to this post.

Comment: Erm, he's talking about a HTTP `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` response. Blindly putting it altogether into a `String` isn't going to work without stripping the chunk headers and newlines first.. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: @BalusC: Just to be clear - I'm not talking about converting the entire `data` byte array to a `String`. No! When the data has been read, then it can be investigated (may be wrapping it by a `ByteArrayInputStream` is a way to go) and some parts of it can be converted to String.